# SelectToUISlider not changing value in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, select-to-slider

I'm creating a slider search control for a site using SelecttoUISlider, everything works great in chrome, IE and on windows phone. however in desktop safari or on an apple device the value of the select in the background does not change. The 'selected' attribute changes, but the physical value of the select element doesn't. as a result i get buggy results and a query string is passed into the results view twice, with different values, causing an error.

Im using pretty standard syntax for the SelectToUISlider. And i have checked that it works with basic jquery UI

Ive made the select element visible in this JSfiddle, incase anyone wanted to see
http://jsfiddle.net/847aypbb/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //<![CDATA[
    // hide the select elements so that the sliders will take over
    //$('.suggest-wrap select').hide();
    // set up the sliders
    $('#group-experience').selectToUISlider({
        tooltip: false, labelSrc: 'text'
    });
    $('#distance-piste').selectToUISlider({
        tooltip: false, labelSrc: 'text'
    });
    $('#hotel-type').selectToUISlider({
        tooltip: false, labelSrc: 'text'
    });
    $('#ski-area').selectToUISlider({
        tooltip: false, labelSrc: 'text'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SelectToUISlider apparently has compatibility issues with iOS in general. Even with Google Chrome on iPad I couldn't get it to work. It works perfectly fine with Chrome on Android, though.

I would recommand to use the .slider() method from jQueryUI, but if you needed a more specific select, then we have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

We had to include the jquery.ui.touch-punch "hack" script to get the sliders to even respond on iOS safari. After we did that, I had the same problem of the drop down values not being set. I believe it's because selectToUiSlider is using old jQuery. In its default sliderOptions' slide function, it sets the selected option using the `.attr` function. I think this only sets the attribute of the element but not the property of its DOM object. I updated the code to this:

```
currSelect.find('option:selected').prop('selected', false);

currSelect.find('option').eq(ui.value).prop('selected', true);
```

The first line may not be necessary, but the key is to use `.prop` instead of `.attr`.